# How to check both defined and parameter passed with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, undefined, jquery-localizer

I have that function:

```
function(stringsVar) {
var stringRes = stringsVar || localize_en;
if('window.'+stringsVar === undefined) {
    stringRes = localize_en;
}
...
}
```

and doesn't work. That was like that actually:

```
function(stringsVar) {
    var stringRes = stringsVar || localize_en;
}
```

that function can take a parameter or not and the code above is checking it correctly. Parameter of that function will be a variable. I want to add that ability to my function. It will check whether that variable is defined or not. If not there is a defined variable at system, localize_en, it will be assigned as default.

How can I correct my code. The second part of my code will be that functionality:
i.e stringsVar is localize_ar and it is not a defined variable (I define that kind of variables with var keyword)

```
if(window.localize_ar === undefined){
alert('yes');}
else {
alert('no');
}
```

I will add that functionality as parametric.

Any ideas?

**PS:** localize_en and something like that variables are object.

**EDIT:** I am working on JQuery localizer plugin => [source code](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/sagimann.localizer.js__0.txt). 
I call it as

```
$('html').localize('localize_' + tr);
```

However it can not understand it as an object, it works as if I do:

```
$('html').localize(localize_tr);
```

It changes it into a string maybe the problem lays on there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [square bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html) to refer to object members whose name is stored in a variable, so you're probably looking for this:

```
if (window[stringsVar] === undefined) {

}
```

Furthermore, the `||` operator will return the first truthy; what happens if an object is passed as the first parameter? That's truthy, but you specifically want a **string**, so whilst the `||` operator looks cool, you might find the following more appropiate:

```
if (typeof stringVar !== "string") {
    stringVar = "localize_en";
}
```

It also looks like you're getting confused when to use a string to refer to the object your targeting, and when not to.

When you going to be doing something like:

```
window[someVar]
```

`someVar` **needs** to be a string.

It is possible to pass an object by reference in JavaScript, and after writing all the above to help you fix the problem you've *currently* got, a better approach will be to pass the object by reference in the first place and avoid the problem *completely*, rather than passing the *name* of the variable storing the object:

```
function(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== "object") { 
        obj = localize_en; // here we're wanting the object itself, rather than the name of the object, so we're not using a string.
    };

    // Now use `obj`. It'll be either the object the user passed, or the default (localize_en).

    // You can even store this in a global variable if you want to:
    window.selected_obj = obj;
}
```

### Edit:

From your comment, try this:

```
function (stringsVar) {
    if (typeof stringsVar !== "string" || typeof window[stringsVar] !== "object") {
        stringsVar = "localize_en"; // Set the default of the argument, if either none is provided, or it isn't a string, or it doesn't point to a valid object
    }

    var stringRes = window[stringsVar];

    // Now do *whatever* you want with stringRes. It will either be the *valid* localization type the parameter specified, or the default ("localize_en").
}
```

You should pass this function a ***string***.

Comment: localize_en, localize_tr are my seperate files and inside of that files I declare them as like var localize_tr = ... I am getting the browser language i.e. ar, I will check that do I have a variable named localize_ar if not then I will use localize_en. On the other hand if I don't want to check browser language I wont pass a parameter to that function and it will behave like localize_en. I want to improve jquery localizer plugin.

Comment: Thanks, works well. Just something to learn, what is the disadvantage of passing an object instead of its name as string? I mean I can check is it an object continue, else branch to your code?

Comment: @kamaci: You're question looses the context we're in; the problem here isn't whether to pass an object or a string, the problem is whether we should pass a string, or a reference to a variable (object or not), that **might not be defined**. I've favoured passing the string in this situation for just that reason; so you don't have to check whether the variable is defined before you pass it *each time you invoke the function*.